# Typescript: list of keys into the object with the same keys and values based on key content

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

We need to type the function, which requires a list of keys (strings) and produces object with the same keys where values are `string | undefined` when key starts with `?` or otherwise just `string`.

```
export function useParams<T extends string>(
  expected: T[]
): { [key in T as NonOptional<T>]: string } {
  // ... our custom implementation
  return null as any;
}

type NonOptional<T extends string> = T extends `?${infer Inner}` ? Inner : T;

// Should produce type { a: string; b: string | undefined }
const result = useParams(['a', '?b']);
```

However, I'm not sure how to type the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write it iterating over tuple's keys:

```ts
export function useParams<T extends readonly string[]>(
  expected: T
): { [K in T[number] as NonOptional<K>]: string | OrUndefined<K> } {
  return null as any;
}

type NonOptional<T extends string> = T extends `?${infer Inner}` ? Inner : T;
type OrUndefined<T extends string> = T extends `?${string}` ? undefined : never

const result = useParams(['a', '?b'] as const);
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W44G4W)

---

Added section to address the problem described in comments:

> I'm pretty sure developers will forgot to add as const and then it will stop working correctly.

To allow passing non-readonly tuples you may use [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094):

```ts
export function useParams<T extends string[]>(
  expected: [...T]
): { [K in T[number] as NonOptional<K>]: string | OrUndefined<K> } {
  return null as any;
}

type NonOptional<T extends string> = T extends `?${infer Inner}` ? Inner : T;
type OrUndefined<T extends string> = T extends `?${string}` ? undefined : never

const result = useParams(['a', '?b']);
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEVd4N)

Comment: Thanks! Looks good but unfortunately, I'm pretty sure developers will forgot to add `as const` and then it will stop working correctly. Any idea how to make it works without `as const`?